# How to access ProjectReference Name with msbuild library

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

MSBuild looks like this for a project reference:

```
   <ProjectReference Include="..\..\ABC\ABC\ABC.csproj">
      <Name>ABC</Name>
      <Project>{XXXXXXXXX}</Project>
      <Package>{YYYYYYYY}</Package>
    </ProjectReference>
```

I need ProjectReference.Name.  I'm using Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine to extract the data.

```
  var projectReference =
        from grp in project.ItemGroups.Cast<BuildItemGroup>()
        from item in grp.Cast<BuildItem>()
        where item.Name == "ProjectReference"
        select item;

    foreach (BuildItem item in projectReference)
    {
        References.Add(item.Name);
    }
```

`item.Name` gives me ProjectReference.  I need "ABC".  How can I get to this data?

Answer (score 2):

I found a pretty good example on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.builditem(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can just change the for loop to extract metadata:

```
   foreach (BuildItem item in projectReference)
    {
        var name = item.GetMetadata("Name");
        References.Add(name);
    }
```

In the cases I've seen `BuildItem` represents an XML element and it's attributes:

```
<element attribute="blah">
  <meta1>hello</meta1>
  <meta2>world</meta2>
</element>
```

The metadata appears to be a buildup of child data.